# Why isinstance('foo', str) == False

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I used `futurize` to gently migrate my modules to Python3 and now I have this at the top of my files:

```
from builtins import str
```

The `future.types.newstr.BaseNewStr` causes me a wrong result for `isinstance`:

```
>>> isinstance('foo', (unicode, str))
False
```

How to properly fix that?

Note that adding `from __future__ import unicode_literals` does not help because the `isinstance` is called from a function called from somewhere else where I don't have the control if `unicode_literals` is properly imported.

**EDIT**

I found that I could use this:

```
def foo(string):
   import six
   if isinstance(string, six.string_types):
      return six.types.StringType('bar')
```

Which looks like very boilerplate...

Comment: Might be because the `str` you're importing resolves into a `class` object ( `type(str)` )where as standard `str` resolves into `type`. That's my guess anyway.

Comment: It seems that you need [native string type](http://python-future.org/what_else.html#native-string-type).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear to me what you wanted to achieve with the boilerplate code, but the correct way to check the instance type is there.
To answer your question to fix the `isinstance` check, you would just do

```
isinstance('foo', six.string_types)
```

Yes, you will also have to import the `six` library everywhere you want to use it, which is common when dealing with python2/3 code.

Btw, if you don't need the python2 compatibility, and just want to migrate to python3, you don't need the imports from the `future` (builtins)